# I have problem with fetching data with laravel when i use relations and paginate

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

what is error when i want to fetching data with paginate(10) the Vue js dosn't do it 
but when i use paginate(5) it working good
this code of Controller with relationship in model files 
and the response status 200 ok working

```
$results = Posts::with(['comment'])
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(5);
        return response()
            ->json(['results' => $results]);
```

this code is actually worked for me but i want to make 10 results in my page
Like this

```
$results = Posts::with(['comment'])
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->paginate(10);
return response()
->json(['results' => $results]);
```

with `->paginate(10)or > 5` not giving any data and get error on console with Vue js but the response is ok 200

Comment: Can you show us a console dump of your data or is it super confidential?

Comment: Might it be that there are fewer than 10 records to display?

Comment: Also if you try`dd($results)` before the return, does the $results object contain the data you expected to see?

Comment: i try this and i make like this application without using vujs  i used laravel from 3 years , sorry  dd() and postman and all things used is done giving me the object json named 
result {
0{}
1{}
2{}
all working

Comment: count of record is 25 records when i use paginate(5) all things working
up-to 5 its giving me an error in console by vuejs :) what happens

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$results = Posts::with('comment')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);

return response()->json(['results' => $results]);
```

Comment: sorry but also noting results in vue js it say error but if i set the paginate(5)
its working